# Xamarin.Forms - How can I dynamically change the height of my CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CarouselView in which I call an object with individual and completely different Views.

The only elements my ContentPage has, are the CarouselView itself, and a bottombar with a gradient above it (notice gradient in following image).

I have done this in a way in which this gradient dissapears when the page's scrolling space becomes 0 (when I have scrolled to the end of the page).

[image]

The problem is that when I swipe between items in the CarouselView, the CarouselView always maintains the height of the very first View that is called in.

This means that, in a View with MORE height than the 1st one, when scrolling up (after being at the very bottom, and therefore not showing a gradient) the gradient will only show again once it hits the height value of the 1st page.

In a View with LESS height than the 1st one, the page will allow me to scroll down until I reach the height value of the 1st page, even if there are not enough elements on the page to even need a scroll.

Essentially, what I am asking for, is if there is a way in which I can, in some way, "refresh" the height of the Page every time a scroll is complete to another View in the CarouselView, resolving my height issues in smaller views, and my gradient issues in larger views.

**Main ContentPage Code Behind (Gradient)**

```
        public double ScrollingSpace
        {
            get
            {
                return MainScrollView.ContentSize.Height - MainScrollView.Height;
            }
            set { }
        }

        // Removes gradient when scroll is complete
        private void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ScrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY) // Touched bottom
                EndPageGradient.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, false); // the view is GONE, not invisible
            else
                EndPageGradient.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, true);
        }

        // Removes gradient if page is not large enough to need scroll
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            if (ScrollingSpace <= 0)
                EndPageGradient.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, false); // the view is GONE, not invisible
        }
```

**Main ContentPage CarouselView XAML**

```
                <CarouselView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList}"
                    Loop="False">

                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

                </CarouselView>
```

**Main ContentPage ViewModel (List with Views for CarouselView)**

```
            ViewList = new List<ContentView>()
            {
                new Step1(),
                new Step2(),
                new Step3(),
                new Step4(),
                new Step5(),
                new Step6(),
                new Step7(),
                new Step8()
            };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Items in a `CarouselView` can be dynamically resized at runtime by changing layout related properties of elements within the `DataTemplate`.You could look at [Dynamic resizing of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/layout#dynamic-resizing-of-items).

Comment: You may try **carouselView.ScaleY(1.2)** to set it back  **carouselView.ScaleY(1)**